Ethereum Transaction Data Decoding
My question is regarding the decoding of transaction data. Specifically, when combing the Ethereum mainnet mempool and getting the transaction data for a transaction. How would I go about getting the contract function called and the data send to the function (human readable or interpretable) through calldata or transaction data. If I'm misusing terminology or don't quite understand what I'm talking about it would be appreciated if you could let me know. I use ethers.js as my main library.

This answer might be helpful.

If you could share more about the transaction data in terms of contract address, ABI, function call. Then, I can provide a more targeted code to decode the same using ethers.js or so.
